# Python typing validation

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, type-hinting

I would like to implement validation for Python 3.6 type annotation within my project.

I have a method that uses `__annotations__` dict to check if all attributes of the class have the correct value. It works perfectly for basic types like `int`, `str` or `bool`, but fails for more sophisticated elements like `typing.Union` or `typing.Optional` (which is also a Union).
The failure is caused by `isinstance()` method within `Union` object that throws `TypeError`. I even cannot find a way to ensure that the annotation is a Union so I cannot validate if a value complies with a type.

The `typing` module does not have any solution for it. Is there a way to validate if specified variable complies with `typing.Union`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. `isinstance` and `issubclass` were [killed](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/136) some time ago for cases like `Union`.

The idea, as also stated [in a comment on the issue by GvR](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/136#issuecomment-138174590) is to implement your own version of `issubclass/isinstance` that use some of the extra metadata attached to types:

```
>>> Union[int, str].__args__
(int, str)
>>> Union[int, str].__origin__
typing.Union
```

`__args__` and `__origin__` are available *as of Python 3.6.3*. They might not in earlier versions since [typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) is still provisional.

Until the internal interface for introspecting types is fleshed out and typing graduates from provisional status, you should expect breakage due to changes in the API.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Unions](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#unions) from typing as here: [pydantic](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic)

Comment: Pydantic uses the same `Union` class from the `typing` module ...

Answer (score 0):

Before using `isinstance()`, you need to check if the annotation is an annotation from module `typing`.
I do it like this:

```
    def _is_instance(self, value: Any, annotation: type) -> bool:

        str_annotation = str(annotation)

        if self._is_typing_alias(str_annotation):

            if self._is_supported_alias(str_annotation):

                is_instance = self._get_alias_method(str_annotation)
                if is_instance is not None:
                    return is_instance(value, annotation)

            exception = TypeError('Alias is not supported!')
            self._field_errors.append(TypingValidationError(
                value_repr=get_value_repr(value), value_type=type(value),
                annotation=annotation, exception=exception
            ))
            return False

        return super()._is_instance(value, annotation)
```

More details here: https://github.com/EvgeniyBurdin/validated_dc/blob/master/validated_dc.py

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstood the question, but, as of 3.10, isinstance worked for me, including on 3.10 style types (using `|` for unions and `|None` for optional).

```
class Check:
    a : int
    b : int|float
    c : str|None

    def __init__(self,a,b,c=None) -> None:
        self.a, self.b, self.c = a,b,c

    def validate(self):
        for k, constraint in self.__annotations__.items():
            v = getattr(self, k, None)
            if not isinstance(v, constraint):
                print(f"\n\n❌{k} : {v} does not match {constraint}")
                return False
        return True


def check(annotation, value):
    print(f"\n\ncheck({locals()})",end="")
    return isinstance(value, annotation)

a = Check.__annotations__["a"]
b = Check.__annotations__["b"]
c = Check.__annotations__["c"]

print(f"✅ {check(a,3)}")
print(f"❌ {check(a,4.1)}")
print(f"✅ {check(b,4.1)}")
print(f"✅ {check(c,None)}")
print(f"❌ {check(b,None)}")

check = Check(a=1,b=2)
print("\n",check.validate(), f"for {check.__dict__}",)

check = Check(a=1,b="2")
print("\n",check.validate(), f"for {check.__dict__}","\n\n")
```

##### output:

```
check({'annotation': <class 'int'>, 'value': 3})✅ True


check({'annotation': <class 'int'>, 'value': 4.1})❌ False


check({'annotation': int | float, 'value': 4.1})✅ True


check({'annotation': str | None, 'value': None})✅ True


check({'annotation': int | float, 'value': None})❌ False

 True for {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': None}


❌b : 2 does not match int | float

 False for {'a': 1, 'b': '2', 'c': None}
```

p.s. changed it to   `c : Optional[str]` and confirmed that worked as well.

p.p.s.

##### All is not rosy.

Having `typing.Any` anywhere resulted in `isinstance` throwing TypeError.

For now I've added a quick and dirty function to see if isinstance will work, for that annotation:

```
@functools.lru_cache
def can_isinstance(anno) -> bool:
    """ check if isinstance is going to throw an error"""
    try:
        isinstance(None, anno)
        return True
    except (TypeError,) as e: 
        return False

    ....
    myvalue = "xxx"
    if can_isinstance(annotation):
        if not isinstance(myvalue, annotation):
           ...
```